# My Raspberry Camera image looks like green

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi2

Due to my reputation, I can't upload image.

http://nipa0711.net/rasp.jpg

I think I can use only one link, so please look at that link first.

////////////////////

I typed this command in terminal.

**raspistill -o image.jpg**

A,B

then the result is that image.

I was detached camera film. [that green thing]

C,D

I tried to take my room using sony a65 with similar option as raspberry pi camera.

You can see both images are very different.

Why my raspberry pi camera image having lots of green pixels?

and how to solve it?

Is that software problem or hardware problem??

/////////////////////

also, I updated firmware too.

**sudo apt-get update**

**sudo apt-get upgrade**

**rpi-update**

nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try reconecting the Pi camera, following the video at https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/camera-module-setup/